# How do a add prefers-color-scheme media query

Tags: color-scheme

Hello I have this code:

```
<script>
function storageAvailable(type) {
 try {
     var storage = window[type],
         x = '__storage_test__';
     storage.setItem(x, x);
     storage.removeItem(x);
     return true;
 }
 catch(e) {
     return e instanceof DOMException && (
         // everything except Firefox
         e.code === 22 ||
         // Firefox
         e.code === 1014 ||
         // test name field too, because code might not be present
         // everything except Firefox
         e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
         // Firefox
         e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
         // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
         storage.length !== 0;
 }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var storageAvailable = window.storageAvailable('sessionStorage');
   $(".et-dark-toggle").click(function() {
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").toggleClass("et-dark-mode");
       if ( storageAvailable ) {
           $("body").hasClass("et-dark-mode") ?
           sessionStorage.setItem('etDarkModeEnabled','1'):
           sessionStorage.removeItem('etDarkModeEnabled');
       }
   });
   if (storageAvailable) {
       '1' == sessionStorage.getItem('etDarkModeEnabled') ?
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").addClass("et-dark-mode"):
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").removeClass("et-dark-mode");
   }
});
</script>
```

How can i add prefers-color-scheme media query to autoenable the created dark mode when user has dark mode enabled in browser ?
Can you please help me

Comment: Can you try with 
if(window.matchMedia)
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
      .addEventListener('change', event => {
  if (event.matches) {
    //dark mode
  } else {
    //light mode
  }
})
You would also want to be aware of the changes of the dark mode.

Comment: could you please help me how to exactly do this with my code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. A quick code to integrate (p.s. not tested):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var storageAvailable = window.storageAvailable('sessionStorage');
   if(window.matchMedia)  
   {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', event =>
            { 
                if (event.matches && !$("body").hasClass("et-dark-mode")) 
                {  
                    $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").addClass("et-dark-mode");
                    if ( storageAvailable )
                    {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('etDarkModeEnabled','1'):

                    } 
                }
                else 
                {
                    $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").removeClass("et-dark-mode");
                    if ( storageAvailable )
                    {
                        sessionStorage.removeItem('etDarkModeEnabled'); 
                    }
                } 
            }
        );
   }
   $(".et-dark-toggle").click(function() {
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").toggleClass("et-dark-mode");
       if ( storageAvailable ) {
           $("body").hasClass("et-dark-mode") ?
           sessionStorage.setItem('etDarkModeEnabled','1'):
           sessionStorage.removeItem('etDarkModeEnabled');
       }
   });
   if (storageAvailable) {
       '1' == sessionStorage.getItem('etDarkModeEnabled') ?
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").addClass("et-dark-mode"):
       $(".et-dark-mode-capable,body").removeClass("et-dark-mode");
   }
});
```

In short it checks if the browser supports **window.matchMedia** and then it reads it and sets the theme based on that preference. In the end it is the same as your code to allow the user to toggle the dark and light mode (maybe a button, or a checkbox).

For more info you can search some [dev blogs on the subject](https://dev.to/search?q=light%20and%20dark%20mode) and after a quick search I would say that [this one might closely match your needs](https://dev.to/albertomontalesi/add-dark-mode-to-your-website-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-5baf)  (p.s. not my blog :) )